# How to automate testing of SQL Server stored procedure which run based on data in different tables

Tags: sql-server

I am planning to write functional test cases for a stored procedure. The procedure doesn't have any input parameter. It reads data from different tables and based on type or state of data it takes different action.

I am thinking of using Node JS testing framework to test stored procedure. This is what I am planning.

1. Create a Node Js project and use test framework mocha.
2. Write test case. Inside test cases use transaction (not sure if that possible).
3. After starting transaction, add mock data into tables based on scenario want 
   to test.
4. execute procedure.
5. Verify change in mock data state using select query.
6. Rollback transaction.

Is there a better way to do functional testing of stored procedure?

This stored procedure is not called in any application. It runs as scheduled job.

Comment: 1) Create a database project using [SSDT](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017). 2) Script the data the procedure needs. 3) At the beginning of the test, deploy the database to a LocalDB instance. 4) Test. 5) There is no step 5. Drop the database if you like; you can also overwrite it as part of step 3. You can use transactions/rollbacks as part of this to speed up testing, but the main idea is that you should not rely on these to start with a predictable clean slate, nor keep around a global, shared database for this.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks for the response. So you are suggesting I should create a new instance of database and run test cases on that instance is this correct?

Comment: @JeroenMostert Also 4th step test. How do you suggest I should do that. Should I use approach (Node Js project ) I mentioned in question.

Comment: You can use whatever testing framework you like for the actual test. If you're using Visual Studio and database projects it obviously makes the most sense to use a unit test project and C#, but that's by no means a requirement. I know there are people who've built dedicated testing frameworks for databases/stored procedures specifically, but I have no personal experience with any. The main idea is testing on a local instance of the database, though. For integration testing, a secondary production database is more instructive, but for unit testing you want to be as local as possible.